# ES6 Spread operator to vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax, ecmascript-2018

I have added a script that uses ES6 spread operator to the project that gets the params from the url. Unsure how to revert this to the normal vanilla Javascript syntax after I discovered that the project doesn't support ES6.

It's easy to take normal Javascript arrays and use the spread operator but in more complicated instances like this one I cannot make the array return the result without totally changing the script.

```
getQueryURLParams("country");

getQueryURLParams = function(pName) {
    var urlObject = location.search
    .slice(1)
    .split('&')
    .map(p => p.split('='))
    .reduce((obj, pair) => {
      const [key, value] = pair.map(decodeURIComponent);

      return ({ ...obj, [key]: value }) //This is the section that needs to be Vanilla Javascript
    }, {});

    return urlObject[pName];
};
```

Thanks to everyone for the replies. After back and forth I realized that the suggestion here that I convert the whole script to ES5 was correct since the browser only complained about that line but other items not ES5 were also problematic.

This is what I had after using ES5:

```
getQueryURLParams = function(pName) {


if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
    // Must be writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true
    Object.defineProperty(Object, "assign", {
      value: function assign(target, varArgs) { // .length of function is 2
        'use strict';
        if (target == null) { // TypeError if undefined or null
          throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
        }

        var to = Object(target);

        for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
          var nextSource = arguments[index];

          if (nextSource != null) { // Skip over if undefined or null
            for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
              // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
              if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
                to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return to;
      },
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    });
  }

var urlObject = location.search
.slice(1)
.split('&')
.map(function(element ) { 
    return element.split('='); 
})
.reduce(function(obj, pair) {  

  const key = pair.map(decodeURIComponent)[0];
  const value = pair.map(decodeURIComponent)[1];

  return Object.assign({}, obj, { [key]: value });
}, {});

return urlObject[pName];
};
```

Comment: ES6 === Vanilla. Do you mean ES5 by chance?

Comment: Also, if it's ES5, then arrow functions should be removed, too.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
return Object.assign({}, obj, { [key]: value });
```

Demo:

```js
const obj = { a: 1 };
const key = 'b';
const value = 2;

console.log(Object.assign({}, obj, { [key]: value }));
```

FWIW, the `{ ...obj }` syntax is called "[Object Rest/Spread Properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread)" and it's a part of ECMAScript 2018, not ECMAScript 6.

Comment: `Object.assign` is ES6

Comment: @Jonathan Yeah, but the OP is using other ES6 features, like arrow functions and computed property names, so I assumed the problem is only with object spread properties, which isn't so widely supported by browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the syntax for `ES5` here is a polyfill for `Object.assing()` ([source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign))

```js
   

// we first set the Object.assign function to null to show that the polyfill works
Object.assign = null;

// start polyfill

if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  // Must be writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true
  Object.defineProperty(Object, "assign", {
    value: function assign(target, varArgs) { // .length of function is 2
      'use strict';
      if (target == null) { // TypeError if undefined or null
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
      }

      var to = Object(target);

      for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
        var nextSource = arguments[index];

        if (nextSource != null) { // Skip over if undefined or null
          for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
            // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
              to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return to;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
}

// end polyfill


   // example, to test the polyfill:

const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

const object2 = Object.assign({c: 4, d: 5}, object1);

console.log(object2.c, object2.d);
// expected output: 3 5
```

Comment: Why would you do `Object.assign = null;` then immediately check if it is a function? The check will be like: _"It's `null`, duh!"_.

Comment: That is part of the polyfill who first checks it. I'll just set it to null for demonstration purposes to show that the polyfill does actually work

Comment: You may want to add clarification so people won't take it literally and just override the maybe-already-there `Object.assign`. A line comment beside it is perfect